# Read BLE characteristics and write them into a file

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Good evening,
i am trying to build an app that connects with an arduino uno with BLE. It is not the center of my project and i had to learn Android programming in a short amount of time. That is why i am mainly using the BluetoothLeGatt app as a reference. My question may seem obvious for some of you.
I've managed to connect to my device but i do not understand how to read/receive notifications.

I understand the link between the functions used : boradcastUpdate, onCharacteristicChanged, onCharacteristicRead... but do not understand how the process starts(e.g how to launch these functions). Am i supposed to call an action myself ? Is there a problem with my emiter ?

I find the documentation of Android unclear and have spent a few hours searching for solutions before coming here.
Thank you for your answers

Comment: Your question shows no attempt at a solution. Your question is very unclear.  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le) about Bluetooth GATT is quite clear about how to setup a basic project and its basic elements. You shouldn't have any problems to read/write on any characteristics your Arduino announce just by adapting a sample project like [this](https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/tree/master/BluetoothGatt).

Basically all you need is work with `BluetoothGatt` class getting a specific `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` of a service, and write into it like [this](https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/blob/master/BluetoothGatt/src/com/example/bluetoothgatt/MainActivity.java#L271) after you've done the scanning and connecting process to your Arduino BLE peripheral.